# Using AllenNLP Interpret with a HuggingFace model

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, allennlp

I would like to use AllenNLP Interpret (code + demo) with a PyTorch classification model trained with HuggingFace (electra base discriminator). Yet, it is not obvious to me, how I can convert my model, and use it in a local allen-nlp demo server.

How should I proceed ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your task is binary classification, you can look at the BoolQ example in https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/main/training_config/classification/boolq_roberta.jsonnet. You can change that configuration to use a different model (such as Electra).

We also just put some new documentation out for the Interpret functionality: https://guide.allennlp.org/interpret

To give you a more specific answer, I'll need to know some more details, like what the task is you're trying to solve, how you trained the original model, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ! I will test with that configuration file, and take a look at the interpret new documentation.I am doing a simple binary classification, and the training was done with the HuggingFace Trainer module.